# pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY) not giving corerct answer

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-package-managers, android-hardware

I want to check if a device has any cameras before trying to open a qr code reader.

I have the following code:

```
 public boolean checkDeviceCompatibility() {

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    return true;
    } else {
    // use front camera
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "This device does not have a back camera so it has automatically reverted to the front camera",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
    }
} else {
    util.displayErrorDialog(
        context,
        "This device does not have any cameras and therefore cannot make use of the QR Code feature.");
    return false;
}
}
```

But now if I run this code in debug mode on my galaxy S3 with two cameras. the first if statement is returned false.

Why could this be?

Comment: check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652189/hassystemfeaturepackagemanager-feature-camera-returns-true-for-device-with-no/25439559#25439559) hope you find it useful here.

Answer (score 6):

[`FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` was added in Android 4.2.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY) `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)` should return `false` for any pre-4.2 device. If your S3 is still on 4.1, that would explain your problem.

Comment: So what is my alternative?

Comment: @Zapnologica: Dump your current code, and [call `getNumberOfCameras()` on the `Camera` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

To make it clear.

`FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` was added to Android 4.2 ( API-17): [Android - developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY).

code:

```
public static boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}
```

Note that using this code will return false if device under version 4.2:

Then you should know that there is a bug with emulator when use `FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` feature (with android 4.2 and above). see: [Emulator does not honour Camera support flag](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14545)

Thats why Im still using old way even its deprecated:

```
public static boolean hasCamera() {
    return android.hardware.Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems that this is the best way. For example packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) gives FALSE on Nexus 7 Kit-Kat 4.4 with Front camera which is a bug since camera is present on the device