# hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) returns true for device with no camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-package-managers

I have a application which uses camera functionality in it but part of its functionality can also run without camera feature. SO I have put this in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required="false"/>
```

and in my code I check whether the device has camera or not using this

```
final boolean deviceHasCameraFlag = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

Now I am testing my code on a tablet which runs Android 4.0(ICS) and has no camera. But still I get True value for the `deviceHasCameraFlag`. Is this weird or am I missing something.

I tried different things and even tried the same thing on Bluetooth feature as Tablet even doesn't have Bluetooth feature. It works fine for Bluetooth but gives me true for camera.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if device has a camera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944117/check-if-device-has-a-camera). Please see the highest voted answer: it will return `true` if the device has front/rear/both camera.

Comment: Yes device does not have a single camera....That's why I am expecting a false value there....

Comment: I posted one code it will works fine i checked practically in both case if it s not having camera and having camera woks fine Just try it

Comment: @y.dixit you will try this below my new code and tell me...

Comment: I have been stuck on this all day now, except with PHONE_STATE permission. Your question helped so much!

Comment: Just have one question, how did you instantiate pm to be the package manager?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia this way,  
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); 
it's there in the second answer that I have posted...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which device is it? The answer you get is a bug, and 4.0 is very old nowadays. Many tablets that still run this version were not crafted correctly, both hardware and software featuring multiple problems.

Regardless, you should always be prepared to handle failure on `Camera.open()` or `Camera.open(0)`: for example, in some cases other software on your device will not release the camera gracefully.

So, in your case you have a false positive, you try to open the camera, it fails, and you continue as if there is no camera on the device, even if **PackageManager** thinks that **PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA** is availabe.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but was not sure to conclude that ...because the same call works for Bluetooth feature and same fails for Camera...So whats the solution here in such device bug case..? Should I leave the application as it is and it will crash on all such buggy devices or should I always check getNumberOfCameras and then proceed.>?

Comment: I don't know what `getNumberOfCameras()` returns on this device. But I  believe that `Camera.open()` will throw, so you should wrap this call with `catch (RuntimeException e) { deviceHasCameraFlag = false; }`. This means that you have to remove `final` from this flag.

Answer (score 10):

Though I have accepted Alex's answer I want to put this answer here showing how to handle hardware failures and bugs.

What I found was in the case of my low standard Android device

```
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)
```

returns true even if the camera doesn't exist and it seems to be a device bug.

So whenever there is a scenario where you need to check, if a camera exists on the device or not, then refer to the solution below to know more about how to handle such failures

```
int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
context = this;
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
final boolean deviceHasCameraFlag = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);

if( !deviceHasCameraFlag || numberOfCameras==0 )
{
  Log.e(TAG, "Device has no camera" + numberOfCameras);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device has no camera",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  captureButton.setEnabled(false);
}
else
{
  Log.e(TAG, "Device has camera" + deviceHasCameraFlag + numberOfCameras);
}
```

In this, I am checking both the number of cameras and if the device has a camera feature Boolean, so even when the system returns an incorrect value for one the other condition would help correct the code.

Comment: Do you open camera only on click of the captureButton? Even if you do so, I would suggest to **try {** `Camera.open()` once (if FEATURE_CAMERA and getNumberOfcameras() checks are positive), and if it throws, write a local file with flag that says "this device cannot capture".

Comment: What I am doing in my code is check if the device has camera or not when the application starts and if camera doesn't exists then disable the capture button for the user so that even if he presses that button nothing happens. So that it doesn't reach the `camera.open()` call.

Comment: I would check rather for the following:

if(deviceHasCameraFlag && numberOfCameras > 0)
{
  //.... device has camera
}
else {
//... no camera
}

Comment: @TashPemhiwa and any particular reason for that? cause I suppose it will be just the another way of doing the same way?

Comment: @y.dixit Well, perhaps it's just a matter of preference, but I find it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had this code:

```
public boolean hasCameraSupport() {
    boolean hasSupport = false;
    if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) { //<- this constant caused problems
        hasSupport = true;
    }
    return hasSupport;
}
```

and it kept returning false on a Genymotion device running Android 4.1.1 (API 16). Once I changed the constant `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` to `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA`, my problems went away. I am guessing that not all devices/API levels support `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY`.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this ... but if you see my code I have used `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA` and not `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY`.

Comment: @y.dixit Perhaps you should try `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY` instead then?

Comment: Yes I agree ...but even it works it won't guarantee that it will work for all devices as in your case it didn't work right? So what my point is we need something which will work on all the devices. I have posted my solution check that once and let me know if you agree to it....

Comment: @y.dixit Yes, it seems likes a solution that would work IMHO, with a slight edit. See my comment above

Comment: FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY is API >= 17, that's maybe why it's returning wrong values on older devices (like the OP's one)

Answer (score 0):

I got it you will try this one definitely it will work....

```
   import android.hardware.Camera;
   int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    if (numCameras > 0) {
      System.out.println("camera");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Camera");
    }
```

Comment: So in my code I should just add `context.getPackageManager()` instead of `getPackageManager()` I will try that. But why does it work for bluetooth then as it is..?

Comment: @kalyanpvs Then whats wrong with my code.....and should it be `Context` or `context` as there is no such `context` thing it prompts me to create local variable when I try to do `context.getPackageManager()`

Comment: It is a Context instance or use like this getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

Comment: If you getting any error just post it,it may use to find the solution

Comment: @NaveenKumar that's what I am saying there is no error in the code....but `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)` returns me true even when device has no camera.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Please edit the answer and remove the first block of code and just keep the second one as it is relevant to the question here....I already did that code i my application and solved my problem but as you have also put that as answer I will accept that as answer for the benefit of the viewers once you remove the first block of code. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

For CameraX, if the FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY method is still returning true when there is no Camera on device, you can add the below method. So whether FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY returns true or false when CameraX is getting initialized, Below method will make sure to do what you want if a camera is actually not available on device.

```
private CameraSelector cameraSelector;
private ProcessCameraProvider cameraAvailableCheck;
private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraAvailableCheckFuture;

private void checkIfAnyCameraExist()
    {

        cameraAvailableCheckFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context);

        cameraAvailableCheckFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    cameraAvailableCheck = cameraAvailableCheckFuture.get();

                    if ((cameraAvailableCheck.hasCamera(cameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA) || cameraAvailableCheck.hasCamera(cameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA) ))
                    {
                        //Do what you want if at least back OR front camera exist

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //Do what you want if any camera does not exist

                    }

                }

                catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | CameraInfoUnavailableException e)

                {
                    // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                    // This should never be reached.
                }
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));


    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Please try this code:

```
private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Still it does't work then please let me know

Comment: have you tried this by this method does it still return `true` ?

Comment: `if (FOO) return true; else return false;` is so redundant... just do `return FOO;`